# How should I use CDO selyear? I get an output file four times larger

Tags: netcdf, netcdf4, cdo-climate

CDO seems to work fine for me, until I met this. I have a netcdf of daily data from year 2101 to 2228, and I want to obtain a file with only years from 2101 to 2227, so I run:

```
cdo selyear,2101/2227 in.nc out.nc
```

But the output file is more than four times the input in memory size! It seems to have the right number of time steps, and the initial and end date are correct. Also, latitude and longitude seem to be the same as the input, so I wonder why the file size.

Comment: Perhaps the initial file had compression applied to it? cdo may have inflated the file in order to perform your operation. See for example https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/blogs/developer/entry/netcdf_compression

Comment: In addition to Rovert Davy: First have a look if `ncdump -k FILENAME` has the same output (it returns the type of NetCDF file). Then have a look via `ncdump -s -h FILENAME` at the attributes `_DeflateLevel` and `_Shuffle` of the variables in your files. A Deflate Level of 0 (or not such attribute at all) means no compression. If you use the command without `-s`, the relevant attributes are not printed.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps try to retain the compression with the cdo operator and output netcdf 4

```
cdo -f nc4c -z zip_9 selyear,2101/2227 in.nc out.nc
```

This is the maximum compression, usually I use `zip_5` or so, as the files are not much larger than `zip_9` and the command is much faster.

[An alternative is to (re?)pack the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71621636/pack-compress-netcdf-data-add-offset-and-scale-factor-with-cdo-nco-or-sim) to SHORTS with add_offset and scale_factor like this:

```
cdo pack -selyear,2101/2227 in.nc out.nc
```