# pack/compress netcdf data ("add offset" and "scale factor") with CDO, NCO or similar

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate, nco, era5

I have heavy netCDF files with floating 64-bits precision. I would like to pack using specific values for the `add_offset` and `scale_factor` parameters (so then I could transform to short I16 precision). I have found information for unpacking with CDO operators but not for packing.

Any help? Thank you in advance!

Edit:

```
diego@LAcompu:~/new$ ncks -m in.nc
netcdf in {
  dimensions:
    bnds = 2 ;
    lat = 202 ;
    lon = 62 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (15777 currently)

  variables:
    float lat(lat) ;
      lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
      lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
      lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
      lat:axis = "Y" ;

    float lon(lon) ;
      lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
      lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
      lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
      lon:axis = "X" ;

    double t2m(time,lat,lon) ;
      t2m:long_name = "2 metre temperature" ;
      t2m:units = "Celsius" ;
      t2m:_FillValue = -32767. ;
      t2m:missing_value = -32767. ;

    double time(time) ;
      time:standard_name = "time" ;
      time:long_name = "time" ;
      time:bounds = "time_bnds" ;
      time:units = "hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0" ;
      time:calendar = "gregorian" ;
      time:axis = "T" ;

    double time_bnds(time,bnds) ;
} // group /
diego@LAcompu:~/new$ ncap2 -v -O -s 't2m=pack_short(t2m,0.00166667,0.0);' in.nc out.nc
ncap2: WARNING pack_short(): Function has been called with more than one argument
diego@LAcompu:~/new$ ncks -m out.nc
netcdf out {
  dimensions:
    lat = 202 ;
    lon = 62 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (15777 currently)

  variables:
    float lat(lat) ;
      lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
      lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
      lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
      lat:axis = "Y" ;

    float lon(lon) ;
      lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
      lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
      lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
      lon:axis = "X" ;

    short t2m(time,lat,lon) ;
      t2m:scale_factor = -0.000784701646794361 ;
      t2m:add_offset = -1.01787074416207 ;
      t2m:_FillValue = -32767s ;
      t2m:long_name = "2 metre temperature" ;
      t2m:missing_value = -32767. ;
      t2m:units = "Celsius" ;

    double time(time) ;
      time:standard_name = "time" ;
      time:long_name = "time" ;
      time:bounds = "time_bnds" ;
      time:units = "hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0" ;
      time:calendar = "gregorian" ;
      time:axis = "T" ;
} // group /
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NCO will automatically pack with optimal values for `scale_factor` and `add_offset` with, e.g.,

```
ncpdq -P in.nc out.nc
```

and you can add lossless compression as well with

```
ncpdq -P -L 1 -7 in.nc out.nc
```

Documentation at http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncpdq

and `ncap2` accepts specific values of `scale_factor` and `add_offset` for per-variable packing with `pack()` documented at http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncap_mth

Demonstration:

```
zender@spectral:~$ ncap2 -v -O -s 'rec_pck=pack(three_dmn_rec_var,-0.001,40.0);' ~/nco/data/in.nc ~/foo.nc
zender@spectral:~$ ncks -m ~/foo.nc
netcdf foo {
  dimensions:
    lat = 2 ;
    lon = 4 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (10 currently)

  variables:
    float lat(lat) ;
      lat:long_name = "Latitude (typically midpoints)" ;
      lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
      lat:bounds = "lat_bnd" ;

    float lon(lon) ;
      lon:long_name = "Longitude (typically midpoints)" ;
      lon:units = "degrees_east" ;

    short rec_pck(time,lat,lon) ;
      rec_pck:scale_factor = -0.001f ;
      rec_pck:add_offset = 40.f ;
      rec_pck:_FillValue = -99s ;
      rec_pck:long_name = "three dimensional record variable" ;
      rec_pck:units = "watt meter-2" ;

    double time(time) ;
      time:long_name = "time" ;
      time:units = "days since 1964-03-12 12:09:00 -9:00" ;
      time:calendar = "gregorian" ;
      time:bounds = "time_bnds" ;
      time:climatology = "climatology_bounds" ;
} // group /
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried this but results are different to the offset and scale parameters I fixed. For example, I use `ncap2 -v -O -s 't2m=pack_short(t2m,0.00166666666666667,0.0);' in.nc out.nc` but results indicate `scale_factor: -0.000784701646794361` and `add_offset: -1.01787074416207`

Comment: It works as advertised for me see above.

Comment: thank you! I edited the post with my code

Comment: Then use pack() not pack_short(), it's the only difference between our commands

Comment: Yes I tried also, with same results for `pack_short`. And also I get this warning `WARNING pack(): Function has been called with more than one argument` that you don't obtain (?)

Comment: That is correct. I do not understand why our results differ. Be sure you are using a recent NCO...

Comment: now it works and I didn't get the warning... thank you very much! it was the version I suppose...

Answer (score 1):

So this was simpler than I thought in cdo

```
cdo pack in.nc out.nc
```

This packs with optimal `add_offset` and `scale_factor`, converting the field to I16.

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually I have other referential datasets with ncdf4 format, short I16, and specific values of offset and scale parameters, so I'm trying to get that specific format, starting from ERA5 downloaded data and then modifying

Comment: ps: sorry for making your comment outdated, I deleted the part of the answer related to compression.